# (404) The request is not recognized during Ti compile

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

When attempting to build my Ti app, run it in the simulator, or run it on my device, suddenly I get this error during compile:

```
[ERROR] :  (404) The request is not recognized!
TRACE  | titanium exited with exit code 100
ERROR  | Error: ti run exited with error code 100
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/natej/.appcelerator/install/4.1.2/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/plugins/run.js:84:66)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:12)
```

I am running latest Appcelerator Studio and building with Ti SDK 4.1.0 GA. I have tried to Clean my project, but that didn't help. Normally when there's a bug in my code I get a helpful error message and it indicates the offending line number. But this tells me nothing and I have no idea what to do about it.

I did find this bug report: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/CLI-764

Anything I can do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently Appcelerator is having issues / is down. You can find more here: https://community.appcelerator.com/topic/151/error-invalid-session-titanium-exited-with-exit-code-100/21

Just wait till they fix it, and you can build again. You can use the old Titanium CLI to build though. Just type `ti build` in CLI

edit: it seems up again

Comment: Thanks Rene. But you'd think that Appcelerator would emit a useful error message when there are server problems, instead of something totally cryptic and misleading that causes thousands of devs stress and wasted time.

Comment: I agree @SweatCoder. Join 300 Titanium Developers on Slack and you'll be one of the first to know! http://topener.nl/tislack

Comment: Sorry for that SweatCoder. We are automating our status updates to better inform you in the future.